# Flex/ActionScript3: keyword "with" hides misspelled property names

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, oop

In Flex 3,

```
var anInstance : MyClass = new MyClass();
with (anInstance)
{
    property1 = "fred";
    property2 = 5;
    propert3 = 7;
}
```

does NOT flag "propert" as a non-existent property name. I thought this was a remainder of the evil JavaScript object behavior (referring to a property name of an object implicitly creates it), but it seems to be a side-effect of the "with".

This makes me very sad as the "with" was a little reminder of Delphi (except it works correctly there).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: How did you decide it wasn't javascript behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading the [documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/index.html):

Actionscript apparently bubbles out for scope resolution on embedded variables (not surprising, since the syntax doesn't require an explicit dereference symbol like "." or "->" to indicate which variable names should be "withed".) So you effectively are creating a variable at global scope named propert3.

---

EDIT after thinking about why this "problem" exists -

Javascript is the epitome of non-strict typing. And Actionscript, being a strict superset of Javascript, can't enforce strict typing except as declared by its own extensions to the language - which means it must support untyped variables.

Comment: That documentation link is local to your machine. I think you might mean http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/index.html

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler then give at least a warning for the variable propert3 not being declared in advance? ... (some minutes testing) ... Nope, it does not.  Furthermore, there is no runtime error, either.

Comment: I hate JavaScript. I enhanced a huge Dojo/Scriptaculous application and I really came to hate loose, squishy languages (I hated Perl before that).

ActionScript 3 is typed tightly enough that I can handle it. Evidently, it has some vestigial squishyness besides Objects.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some classes are dynamic (e.g. movieclip) and can have properties added to them at runtime:

http://flexblog.faratasystems.com/?p=95

Comment: Ahhhhh!!!! I hate classes that are not closed (except to inheritance). That's one reason I don't do Ruby.

What's the point of strict typing if it does not catch freaking membership!

I'm done ranting now.